# How to create excel filter with two columns simultaneously

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, excel-2010

Let's say I have the following excel table:

I want to create a filter for this table that would work in the following way:

```
CONTRACT #  Anniv   Status
Contract 1  101     To Do
Contract 2  201     To Do
Contract 3  201     To Do
Contract 4  201     Done
Contract 5  301     To Do
Contract 6  1001    To Do
Contract 7  501     To Do
Contract 8  501     Done
Contract 9  601     Done
Contract 10 701     Done
```

- I only want to see the Contracts for this current month. For example. Lets say the current month is February. Then I would only want to see the contracts that have an anniversary day of "201" aka the ones highlighted in blue above.
- Second. I want to filter by status so that I only see the ones with TO DO.
- Third. The TO DO filter would have priority over the anniversary day filter. As you can see,  Contract 1 has an anniversary day of 101 but it's status is still TO DO. So it should still show up when I look at all the February statuses with TO DO.

The final outcome should be something like this:

```
Contract #  Anniv   Status
Contract 1  101     To Do
Contract 2  201     To Do
Contract 3  201     To Do
```

I'm trying to do this using advanced filtering. What I've done is create two extra separate columns. One which concatenates the Anniv column so that I just have the month. Then another column which tells me the current month using the Month(Today()) function which returns the current month. I would then like to create an advanced filter which would show all months which are below the current month in value and has a status of To Do. Is there an easier way of doing this or would this be the best approach?

Comment: Have you tried typing `2*` on the filter by text?

Comment: that won't work because I need it to be a dynamic filter. Aka if the month is march it should look for 03, if it's april it should look for 04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach seems sound, though might perhaps be simplified. With your data in A4:C14 below I placed the criteria in A1:D2 and directed the output to F4:H4 :

[image: SO22464436 example]

The formula in D2 is:

```
=B5<=F$1
```

F1 generates the "current month" indicator but adds an offset (obtained from H1) so though it is presently April F1 returns `201` as your example. You may want to change H1 to `0`.